# Male dog was forcefully removed from female dog

Tags: dogs, breeding

A male dog mounted my female dog for like 2 minutes and my brother forced the male out of the female, will the male release sperm in her?

Answer (score 4):

It can but of more importance is that fact that you can seriously injure both dogs. Don't ever force separate mating dogs. You can still have the female spayed and head off pregnancy.

You can read more about it at our existing question [Why does my dog get stuck to the female after mating?](https://pets.stackexchange.com/q/936/13)

Comment: Welcome to Pets! If you have a minute, please take the [tour] and have a look at the [help]. I'd like to add that dogs "stick together" for several minutes *after* the male ejaculated, which makes seperating them pointless. Could you please [edit] your question to add in this detail?

Comment: I added a link to our existing question in your answer.  References are always good, and links to existing posts on our site even better.